# ajax requests within extjs widgets

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

hey all I'm a newb programmer trying to learn some stuff about js, extjs and now i'm super new to AJAX requests. I have an old extjs code.. that made a widget window and had a button that alerted 'stuff' how can i make it so that it pulls from a txt file and changes the value of 'stuff' to something new from the txt file??. I don't know if there's a real use for this i'm just kinda screwing around to familiarize myself with ajax here's my code.

```
function loadXML()
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            xmlhttp.open("get", "ajax_info.txt", true);
            xmlhtpp.send();
        }
    }
}

Ext.define('ryan', {

    constructor: 
        function(){

            Ext.create('widget.window',{
                 //attributes 

                items: [{
            itemId: 'button1',
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'click the button',
             handler: function() {
                     alert('stuff');
                                                       }
    .... // more code
```

I want to use ajax in handler of the items section. alert (stuff then changes when ajax request happens)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this JS was retrieved from a server and is running in a browser.  If so, it's not easy to read files with JS from within a browser.

"stuff" can come from the server - perhaps via an AJAX call - or you might determine "stuff" via other logic in your JS.

I know this is not a particularly helpful answer, but if I discouraged a newbie from trying to read text files using JS, then it's a good answer.

Comment: well it was retrieved from a localhost... not a url. I'm just learning stuff on my own macine... it's running on google chrome... I know I can do it with JS but im learning the syntax or AJAX and trying to play around with it to familiarize myself.

Comment: OK - localhost running Apache or something like that?  Good.

Browsers purposely make it difficult to read/write arbitrary data to a client machine.  So, if you're just starting you prob want to avoid that.